# mkdir: cannot create directory : Protocol error : Virtualbox Shared folder

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to create folders and file in Virtualbox shared folder from Host to guest.
But i get this error `mkdir: cannot create directory : Protocol error`.

```
Below are steps i performed to share folder
1:My host OS is Ubuntu and my guest is Ubuntu.

2:I attached a share folder to virtualBox VM 
  Folder Path:/DR/vault/config 
  Folder:config selected automount and make permanent.

3:In Guest OS i installed virtualbox guest additions

4:I am trying to mount folder on /mount/config path
  I added entry in guest's /etc/fstab as 
  /config         /mount/config  vboxsf  rw,uid=1000,gid=1000      0       0
```

Path gets successfully mounted after Guest reboot also i can see the files created in /DR/vault/config(Guest)  to  /mount/config(Guest) but i cant create folder or file in  /mount/config (Guest)

Please suggest if anything is missing or if there is any other way.

Comment: Is user you use in guest OS in a group "vboxfs"? But if not, you would get another (permission) error message, I guess.

Comment: Also, should shared folder's name (first parameter on line in `fstab`) start with a slash? It should be exactly the same as "Folder name" in machine's settings in Virtualbox. Try it without that slash. I'm not using slash on neither place.

Comment: Hi Dipak, were you able to resolve this? I receive exactly the same error. If nothing works, might have to create the VM from scratch as suggested here: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=45884

Comment: @DawidFerenczy Thanks suggesting buddy....I found problem...My /DR/vault/config path has permission 0750 so it was not allowing to mount path inside guest. i changed it to 0770 and now it works Fine

Comment: @AafreenSheikh Links was really helpfull thanks Aafreen :)

Comment: People mention path length and permissions, but I think also the chars in the path are important. I'm seeing problems when unpacking files with colons (':') in their names, like files from /var/crash in CentOS: 'tar: var/crash/127.0.0.1-2022-09-26-05\:45\:56: Cannot mkdir: Protocol error'. The same archive has longer path names that work fine.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had the drive full, clearing some space on the drive solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this is a problem with filename lengths on DOS hosts.
I have been using VirtualBox VMs as a form of containerised environment for deploying to a JBoss server, having experienced far too many problems with Windows environments for said technology. 
I was using a shared-directory with my host machine as I was trying to keep the virtual machine lightweight (i.e. keeping IDEs in the host machine), then checking code into the shared directory for deployment with Maven. However, maven was giving some odd errors when the directory length grew to over 255 characters. Try looking at your file absolute path (type "pwd") and seeing if it's longer than 255.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this problem with the following:

1. On the **guest** machine, add your user to `vboxsf` group: `sudo adduser username vboxsf`
2. Restart the **host** machine.

My host OS is Windows, my guest OS Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an indication that the folder does not have the correct permissions on the Virtualbox host.

E.g. my headless Virtualbox server is running as "vbox" user, so I had to give that user write permissions on the host folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, turns out that for me it was the number of folders or length of path name involved in mkdir.

*typically I had : 
mkdir -p /projects/bot/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/center-align/node_modules/align-text/node_modules/kind-of/node_modules/is-buffer
Manually I could create up to the last part of the path but not the 'is-buffer'* folder

I am working in vagrant and my projects folder is a shared VM folder, maybe/**probably windows' max path length is the reason**.