# Cannot create a directory, despite changing file permissions

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox, chmod, mkdir

I'm using vagrant. In the folder above, I do

`sudo chmod -R 777 www`

I go inside

`www`

Then I look around

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  28 Jan  8  2012 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 170 Jul 23 07:03 stuff`

I try to make a directory

`mkdir folder
mkdir: cannot create directory 'folder': Protocol error`

I have no idea what's going on or how to fix this. I'm using vagrant on virtual box with Ubuntu guest on OSX 9

Comment: absolutely no one knows... WHOO!!!

Comment: The top Google hit for that error message is this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385570/mkdir-cannot-create-directory-protocol-error-virtualbox-shared-folder). This [SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/233606/virtualbox-problems-writing-to-shared-folders-guest-additions-installed) might also be helpful.